# Invalid index 6 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count= 6

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

**Map Class**

```
public class cAdministratorMap : ClassMap<cAdministrator>
{

    public cAdministratorMap()
    {
        Table("Administrators");

        CompositeId<cAdministratorsKey>(c => c.Key)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Client_id, "client_id")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Start_date, kp => kp.ColumnName("start_date").Type(DbType.Date.ToString()))
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Adm_type, kp => kp.ColumnName("adm_type").Type(DbType.AnsiString.ToString()));

        Map(x => x.Person_id, "person_id").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
        Map(x => x.end_date).Column("end_date");
        Map(x => x.description).Column("description").Length(200);

        References(x => x.Person).Column("person_id");
        References(x => x.Cliente).Column("client_id");

    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Invalid index 6 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count= 6

Please help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Client Id` is mapped twice, once in your `cAdministratorsKey` mapping and again in your `Cliente mapping`.

Remove the `Cliente` mapping and change the `cAdministratorsKey` mapping to include a reference to the `Cliente` property as shown below:

```
  CompositeId<cAdministratorsKey>(c => c.Key)
        .KeyReference(x => x.Cliente, "client_id") // Changed to KeyReference
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Start_date, kp => kp.ColumnName("start_date").Type(DbType.Date.ToString()))
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Adm_type, kp => kp.ColumnName("adm_type").Type(DbType.AnsiString.ToString()));

  // References(x => x.Cliente).Column("client_id"); Removed as not needed
```

This should remove the duplication and fix your issue.

Comment: This also occurs when you map a HasOne entry if you declare the ForeignKey - make sure your foreign key field isn't declared as a property if you do this.

Comment: This also happens when you're modifying more than one object type inside the same scope.